# How to show that there is no such measurable $T$ that pushforwards $\mu$ to $\nu$?

Tags: probability, analysis

The Monge problem in optimal transport is that consider two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $R$ and let $T$ be any Borel measurable mapping that pushforwards $\mu$ to $\nu$ (i.e. $T$ is a measurable map so that for any measurable sets $A$, $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\nu(A)$). Then we want to find the infimum value of
$$
\inf_{T}\int \|T(x)-x\|\mu(dx).
$$
If we take $d\mu(x)=\delta(x)dx$ and $d\nu(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx$ (or $\nu\sim Ber(1/2)$). How to show that there is no such measurable $T$ that pushforwards $\mu$ to $\nu$.

---

If there is such map $T$, then we have for every $x\in R$,
$$
\delta(T^{-1}(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}
$$

Is there such $x$ solving the above equation? Or there is just an empty set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pushforward of a dirac measure will still be a dirac measure. The solution is to split mass, i.e., replace the Monge problem by a Kantorovich optimal transport problem. See, e.g. [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~qlxia/Research/monge.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eqlxia/Research/monge.pdf)
for a friendly discussion.